# Change value within array based on input in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to locale the correct sub-array in order to change the `count`, if a specific value is present more than once.

I have the following code:

```
$trending = [];

foreach($hashtags as $hashtag) {
    if(in_array($hashtag->hashtag, $hashtags))
    {
       array_search()
    }
    else {
       array_push($trending, [
         'hashtag' => $hashtag->hashtag,
         'counts' => '1'
          ]);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following example outout:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(2) 
    { 
        ["hashtag"]=> "foobar" 
        ["counts"]=> "1" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) 
    { 
        ["hashtag"]=> "hashtags" 
        ["counts"]=> "1" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(2) 
    { 
        ["hashtag"]=> "imageattached" 
        ["counts"]=> "1" 
    } 
}
```

So in the `foreach` loop and the `if statement`, i want to check for dublicates of hashtags, e.g. if the hashtag `foobar` exists more than one time, I don't want to create another dublicate in the array, but I want to change the `count` to `2`

**How do I find the correct "sub"-array, and change the `count` of this to `2`, if a hashtag is present within `$hashtags` more than once??**

The idea is, that I at the end can sort these arrays, and get the hashtag that is most common, by looking at the `count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the structure of your output, you could do something like this:

```
$trending = [];
foreach($hashtags as $tag) {
    if (isset($trending[$tag])) $trending[$tag]++;
    else $trending[$tag] = 1;
}
```

Which would result in `$trending` having the structure

```
array(2) {
    ["foobar"] => 1,
    ["hashtags"] => 2
}
```

Which could then be looped through with

```
foreach($trending as $tag => $count) {
    echo $tag . ' appears ' . $count . ' times.' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Ahh you beat me to that recommendation. +1 for the approach you recommended :P

Answer (score 0):

The PHP method **array_count_values** might be of some help.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Might be? What kind of answer is that

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a keyed array?

```
$trending = array();

foreach($hashtags as $hashtag) {
    if(!isset($trending[$hashtag])){
        $trending[$hashtag] = 1;
    }else{
        $trending[$hashtag] += 1;
    }
}
```

By using a keyed array, there is no duplication and you can easily check how frequently a hashtag is used by just accessing `$trending[$hashtag]`. Additionally, you can get the list of all hashtags in the trending array using `$allHashtags = array_keys($trending);`.

Of course, if your project specifications do not allow for this, then by all means, use a different approach, but that would be the approach I would take.

Answer (score 0):

It can be more linear of you can change your array structure but for the current this should work.

```
$trending = [];
$checker  = true;
foreach($hashtags as $hashtag) {
    foreach ($trending as $key =>$value) {
        if($value["hashtag"] == $hashtag->hashtag){
            $trending[$key]["counts"]++;            
            $checker = false;
        }
    }

if($checker) {
       array_push($trending, [
         'hashtag' => $hashtag->hashtag,
         'counts' => '1'
          ]);
    }
$checker  = true;    
}
```